# How to separate values in a list

Tags: c#

I have the following class Node defined like that :

```
class Node
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
        public string Sign { get; set; }
        public Node Parent { get; set; }
        public IList<Node> Children { get; set; }
        public Node()
        {
            Children = new List<Node>();
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Node: " + Operator + " " + Id + " "
            + string.Join(",", Children.Select(x => string.Format("({0}, {1})", x.Sign, x.Id)));
        }
}
```

How can I  get `Sign` and `Id` separately ? I tried the following code :

```
var map = new Dictionary<int, Node>();
foreach (var pair in foo)
{
  string body = "";
  Identifier = pair.Value.Id;
  scope = getScope(Convert.ToString(Identifier));
  var flattenedList = pair.Value.Children.Select(x => x.Sign+x.Id).ToList();

  for (int i = 0; i < flattenedList.Count - 1; i++)
    {
         body = body + flattenedList[i].ToString;//Here I am looking to get separately sign and Id for further treatment .
    }

   }
```

Comment: What's not working? This `x.Sign+x.Id` is not correct since `Id` is an int, but can be easily solved with `Id.ToString()`. Is there any other problem?

Comment: Can you explain how you are going to use Sign and Id separately? As I can see you are concatenating them all in one string `body`. Why you need them separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of concatenating `Sign` and `Id` here

```
var flattenedList = pair.Value.Children.Select(x => x.Sign+x.Id).ToList();
```

select the nodes themselves:

```
var flattenedList = pair.Value.Children.ToList();
```

Then, inside the loop, you can access `Sign` and `Id` separately:

```
var sign = flattenedList[i].Sign;
var id = flattenedList[i].Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using SelectMany extension method which is designed to for this purpose

e.g.

```
var flist = pair.Value.Children.SelectMany(x => x.Children, (n, c) => new { n.Id, c.Sign });
```

will return flattern list of id and sign.